# How to Analyze Binary Navigation Data

Tags: navigation

I have raw binary data for the navigation system, and research has found that currently it is mostly analyzed using SBF files or ublox files. However, I simply want to use binary data for analysis. I know the satellite system, frequency band, start time, satellite number, and other information of this data. What tools should I seek for analysis?

I research found that currently it is mostly analyzed using SBF files or ublox files